# Why does Swift Firebase auth() respond late?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Why does the auth() function respond late? When status returns, it always returns the value defined at the beginning of the function. Is there a way to call auth() createUser with a function?

```
func register(email: String, password: String) -> Dictionary<String, Any> {
    var status = ["stat": false] as Dictionary<String, Any>
    let handle = Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in
        if error != nil {
            status["stat"] = false
            status["statement"] = error!.localizedDescription as String
        } else {
            status["stat"] = true
        }
    }
    return status
}
```

> The handle function returns before the end of the register function.

Comment: What do you mean by late? Are you referring to the completion handler  `result`?

Comment: The 'register' function returns without assigning a value to 'handle'.

Comment: I think to get a value in `handle` like user details you have to use, `result.user`. Completion handler takes time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`createUser` is an asynchronous method, you can delay the return value until `createUser` is completed, but it's not the best way to handle asynchronous methods.

If you give a completion block to your original method like:

```
func register(email: String, password: String, completion: @escaping(([String: Any]) -> Void)) {
    var status: [String: Any] = ["stat": false]
    let handle = Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in
        if error != nil {
            status["stat"] = false
            status["statement"] = error!.localizedDescription as String
        } else {
            status["stat"] = true
        }

        completion(status)
    }
}
```

Then in any other place, you can be sure that `createUser` has completed its course:

```
register(email: "email", password: "password") { status in
    // Now it's ready.
    print(status)
}
```